# how to get jquery getJSON next and previous

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the current page for the getJSON inside another getJSON? is this right? What is the best way to get next and previous on the json below.

```
var currentPage="`http://www.test127.com/ajax/list/?format=json`";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON( currentPage, function( data ) {
    $('#next').click(function(){
       currentPage = data.next
       $.getJSON(  data.next, function( data1 ) {
         $.each( data1.results, function(a,b) {
           $( "#change" ).html( "subject:" + " " + b.subject + " " + b.date );
         });
       });
     });
     $('#prev').click(function(){
        $.getJSON(  data.previous, function( data2 ) {
           $.each( data2.results, function(a,b) {
               $( "#change" ).html( "subject:" + " " + b.subject + " " + b.date );
            });
         });
      });
  });
});
```

data.next is "http://www.test127.com/ajax/list/?page=2&format=json"

```
{"count": 18, "next": "http://www.test127.com/ajax/list/?page=2&format=json",
 "previous": null, 
 "results": [{"subject": "ronald birthday", 
              "date": "2014-06-13", "time_start": "11:17 PM"},
              {"subject": "ronald birthday", "date": "2014-06-19",
               "time_start": "7:17 PM"}]}
```

Comment: Can you maybe explain what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?

It would probably help you understand how to solve whatever it is, if you use better variable names and write the code in such a way so that you don't repeat yourself... it's easier to read and understand.

For example, you could write yours as such:

```
var currentPageUrl="`http://www.test127.com/ajax/list/?format=json`";

function getPageData(url){
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    $.each(data.results, function(a,b) {
          $( "#change" ).html( "subject:" + " " + b.subject + " " + b.date );
     });
  });
}

function loadCurrentPage(){
  $.getJSON(currentPageUrl, function( pageData ) {
        $('#next').click(function(){
           currentPageUrl = pageData.next
           getPageData(currentPageUrl);
         });
         $('#prev').click(function(){
           currentPageUrl = pageData.previous
           getPageData(currentPageUrl);
         });
}

$(document).ready(loadCurrentPage);
```

Now if something isn't doing what you think it should, it's probably going to be easier to spot..

If you give a better explanation of your question, you might get better assistance.